# What are current best practices for development database credential management?

Tags: database, security

In our shop we store credentials for Test and Prod resources in a secured vault and our CI/CD pipelines manage retrieval and provide access by the apps to those credentials at run time. This works great.

However, the vaulting mechanism is not accessible from a local development workstation which makes management of credentials to our Dev database a hassle.

Various mechanisms have been suggested:
1. give each dev access to the DB on their specific credentials

The concern here is that apps are not owned by specific teams so anyone new to the code base would need to request db accesses to be setup.

2. use a common account and share credentials among the team

One sharing approach suggested is to check the shared credentials into the code repo as an environment specific configuration. provided those credentials have limited access (dev db, read,write permissions) and the data bears no relation to real data, its low risk. (We also have on-premise code repository thats not publicly accessibly)
Another is to store the creds in plain text on a secured location. But that requires the dev to locate the creds each time they get a local copy of the code.it also opens the risk that a file setup for the app gets inadvertently checked into the code repository. (see above)

What are others doing to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A couple alternate options that I've done.

Get everyone use a local db - understand this might not be viable depending on your scenario. DEVs could restore their local databases from backup (taken from say a test environment), OR (for new/greenfield projects), you could use a local containerised database where all DDL and config data is created via database migration framework - the latter is what we do at my workplace (we're using SQL Server and [DbUp](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp) as migration framework). Note: we're not seeding the database with test data, but this is something you can also look into...

Use [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) (or something similar) for transparent encryption and decryption of specific files in a git repository e.g. config file containing database password.